# How to see that Poincaré coordinates cover only part of AdS

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, ads-cft

Consider (d+1)-dimensional AdS space of radius $\ell$ as defined by its embedding in $R^{2,d}$ :
$$
-X_0^2 + \sum_{i} X_i^2-X_{d+1}^2 = -\ell^2
$$

Now we can parametrize this surface by the Poincaré coordinates as follows :
$$
X_{\mu} = \ell\frac{x_\mu}{z}\, (\mu=0 ... d-1),\,\, X^d = \frac{\ell}{2z}(1-x^2-z^2),\,\, \\X^{d+1}=\frac{\ell}{2z}(1+x^2+z^2)
$$

Where $x_\mu x^\mu = x^2$ and $0<z<\infty$.

It is widely known that this parametrisation does not cover the full space. My question is, how does one see that ? One way I came up with is to notice that $X^d+X^{d+1}=\frac{\ell}{z}>0$, so that necessarily this parametrisation cannot cover the whole AdS.

However, is there a more "surefire" way of proving that a parametrisation does not cover the surface fully ? For example, if I go into global coordinates, how can I be sure that they do cover the full surface ?

Comment: I think that the rigorous way to argue about covering half the space of the full space is to examine the Penrose diagram. This is done in many places in the literature; see for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0689 chapter 2 and page 19 and below of for a detailed exposition